# variational derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n,\ n=1,2 \mbox{ or } 3$.

Define the following energy

$$E=\int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\left[f(u)+\frac{\varepsilon^2}{2}|\gamma(n)\nabla u|^2\right]\,dx$$

where,

$$n=\frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|}$$

this problem talking about the derivation of Cahn-Hilliard System, $\gamma$ defines the anisotropy function, we take it as general as we want e.g.

$$\gamma(n)=1+\Gamma(n)$$ 
and $f \in C^3(\Omega)$.

the point is that the article talk about the variational derivative of $E$ w.r.t. $u$ and he get the following
$$\frac{\delta E}{\delta u}=f'(u)-\varepsilon^2 \nabla \cdot \textbf{m}$$
where,
$$\textbf{m}= \gamma^2 \textbf{p}+\gamma\ |\textbf{p}|\ \textbf{P} \nabla_n \gamma$$

with $$\textbf{p}=\nabla u\ ,\ \textbf{P}=|\nabla u|\ \frac{\partial n}{\partial \textbf{p}}$$

i start working in the variational derivative i get the following

\begin{eqnarray*}
\delta E &=&\int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\left[f'(u) \delta u+\varepsilon^2 (\gamma(n) \nabla u)\delta(\gamma(n) \nabla u)\right]\,dx\\\\
&=& \int_{\Omega}\frac{1}{\varepsilon} \left[ f'(u) \delta u+\varepsilon^2(\gamma(n) \nabla u)\left(\delta(\gamma(n)) \nabla u+\gamma(n)\delta(\nabla u)\right)\right]\,dx
\end{eqnarray*}

my problem is that i don't know how to continue to get $\textbf{m}$. any help?

$\textbf{Remark :}$ This problem mentioned in "S. Torabi, S. Wise, J. Lowengrub , A New Method for Simulating Strongly Anisotropic Cahn-Hilliard Equations"

Comment: this problem talking about the derivation of Cahn-Hilliard System, $\gamma$ defines the anisotropy function, we take it as general as we want e.g. $$\gamma(n)=1+a\Gamma(n)$$ and $f$ is a $C^3(\Omega)$.

Comment: You may wanna add those information into your question, where did you get stuck.

Comment: the point is that the article talk about the variational derivative of $E$ w.r.t. $u$ and he get the following $$\frac{\delta E}{\delta u}=f'(u)-\varepsilon^2 \nabla \cdot \textbf{m}$$, where  $$\textbf{m}=\gamma^2 \nabla u + \gamma\ |\nabla u|^2 \frac{\partial n}{\partial(\nabla u)} \nabla_n \gamma $$ my problem is how he get $\textbf{m}$?

Comment: the name of the article that this point mentioned is ", S. Torabi, S. Wise, J. Lowengrub , A New Method for Simulating Strongly Anisotropic Cahn-Hilliard Equations."

Comment: when i work on it i get \begin{eqnarray*} \delta E &=& \int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \left[ f'(u) \delta u+\varepsilon^2 (\gamma(n)\nabla u)\delta(\gamma(n)\nabla u) \right]\,dx\\\\ &=& \int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \left[ f'(u) \delta u+\varepsilon^2 (\gamma(n) \nabla u)(\delta(\gamma(n))\nabla u+ \gamma(n) \delta(\nabla u))\right] \,dx \end{eqnarray*} the point now is how i continue to get $\textbf{m}$.

Comment: Nice addition, I suggest you add the contents in your comments to the question. Just click the "edit" button under the question, then you can add as much as you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$E=\int_{\Omega} \left[f(u)+\frac{\varepsilon^2}{2}|\gamma(n)\nabla u|^2\right]dx$$
The variational/functional/Gateaux derivative is given by
$$\delta E(u)(v)=\frac{d}{d\delta} E(u+\delta v)|_{\delta=0}$$
for all $v \in C_c^1(0,T)$. Hence
$$E(u+\delta v) = \int_\Omega  f(u+\delta v) + \frac{\epsilon^2}{2} 
\left|\gamma(n(u+\delta v))(\nabla u + \delta \nabla v) \right|^2 dx$$
and taking the derivative
$$\frac{d}{d\delta}E(u+\delta v) =  \int_\Omega  f'(u+\delta v)v + \epsilon^2 
\gamma(n(u+\delta v)) (\nabla u + \delta\nabla v ) \Big(\gamma(n(u+\delta v))\nabla v + \gamma'(n(u+\delta v)) n'(u+\delta v) v (\nabla u + \delta \nabla v)\Big)dx$$
and setting $\delta=0$
$$\frac{d}{d\delta}E(u+\delta v)|_{\delta=0} =  \int_\Omega  f'(u)v + \epsilon^2 
\gamma(n(u)) \nabla u \Big(\gamma(n(u))\nabla v + \gamma'(n(u)) n'(u) v \nabla u\Big)dx$$
and integration by parts
$$\frac{d}{d\delta}E(u+\delta v)|_{\delta=0} =  \int_\Omega  f'(u)v - \epsilon^2 
\nabla \cdot \Big(\gamma(n(u)) \nabla u \gamma(n(u))\Big) v  + \epsilon^2 
\gamma(n(u)) \nabla u \gamma'(n(u)) n'(u)  \nabla u  v dx$$
and by the fundamental theorem of calculus of variations
$$\frac{d}{d\delta}E(u+\delta v)|_{\delta=0} =  f'(u) - \epsilon^2 
\nabla \cdot \Big(|\gamma(n(u))|^2 \nabla u \Big)   + \epsilon^2 
\gamma(n(u))  \gamma'(n(u)) n'(u)  |\nabla u|^2     $$

Comment: After 6 years the answer written by @Fritz